# How to remove a stuck oil plug?

Tags: chevrolet

I have a stuck oil plug. I've tried a hammer on my ratchet. I don't have a longer bar to use. What can I do to get the plug off? It seems stuck. I'm using a 13 mm socket on a Chevy venture.

Comment: This may seem like a stupid question, *but are you sure you are turning it the correct direction to loosen it?* Righty tighty (clockwise), lefty loosey (counter-clockwise)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lubricant to penetrate the bolt. Some ones that work well are WD-40, Liquid Wrench or PB Blaster, all of which can be found in most hardware stores. If you can get one of those and a hollow metal pipe to get more leverage on the breaker bar, it should do the trick. Be careful when you're down there as it could get real messy once you get it off.

This answer provides details of the above technique on a lug nut. You would follow the same procedure, again just be careful of the oil spill and ensure that that you have the car safely mounted on jack stands: [How do I loosen stuck lug nuts in order to change a tire?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/2204/how-do-i-loosen-stuck-lug-nuts-in-order-to-change-a-tire)